# convert ddmmyy date into prompt in universe SAP BO

Tags: business-objects

I need to display last 2 years of data based on the what date the user enters:

If the user enters 01/01/2015, I need to see data from 01/01/2013 to 01/01/2015

The date will be entered in dd/mm/yy (datetime) format.

How do I achieve this in Webi?

I tried the below code in my universe level filter

```
DIM_GROUP_CONTRACT.GRP_CONTRACT_EFFECTIVE_DATE between
TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(trunc(To_date(@Prompt('Select Reporting End Month: ',
'A','Record Effective Date\Record Effective Month',mono,free,persistent)
||'01','YYYYMMDD'),-24),'MM'), 'YYYYMM')) 

and TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(trunc(Add_Months(To_date(@Prompt('Select Reporting End Month: ',
'A','Record Effective Date\Record Effective Month',mono,free,persistent)
||'01','YYYYMMDD'),'MM'), 'YYYYMM'))
```

It gives me error.

The requirement is to add date in dd/mm/yy format.

Comment: You seem to be forcing the result to the first day of the month.  Is that intentional?  Also, what is in "Record Effective Month"?  It is a six-character string?

Comment: sorry I think I just copied the other object filter's code ...I am sort of new to this thing.I don't need the record effective month. My only requirement is GRP_CONTRACT_EFFECTIVE_DATE which is in form of ddmmyy...

Comment: Here is the code I am using but it gives me an error...add_months(@prompt ('Enter Date:','D','Group Contract Details\Group Contract Effective Date',Mono,Free ),-24) and (@prompt ('Enter Date:','D','Group Contract Details\Group Contract Effective Date',Mono,Free ))

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution

```
DIM_GROUP_CONTRACT.GRP_CONTRACT_EFFECTIVE_DATE between  
add_months(@prompt ('Enter Date:','D','Group Contract Details\Group Contract Effective Date',Mono,Free ),-24) 
and  (@prompt ('Enter Date:','D','Group Contract Details\Group Contract Effective Date',Mono,Free ))
```

thanks